# How to redirect to https://example.com/ instead of https://example.com:443/ on AWS ALB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, load-balancing, amazon-elb, http-redirect

I have configured the following redirect rule to my AWS Application Load Balancer to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS:

[image: redirect rule]

The issue is that when I now `curl` (or visit the domain in the browser), I will get this ugly and redundant `Location` response (domain changed to example.com):

```
~ $ curl -I http://www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: awselb/2.0
Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2020 18:28:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 150
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.example.com:443/
```

I know that `https://www.example.com:443/` is in practice just fine, and I know that it will not be shown in the end user's browser's URL field. But still, it will be shown in the browser's network tab's 'Response headers', and to me it just looks unprofessional compared to a redirect without the port, e.g.:

```
~ $ curl -I http://www.apple.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: AkamaiGHost
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://www.apple.com/
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Mon, 14 Sep 2020 18:33:23 GMT
Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2020 18:33:23 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
Set-Cookie: geo=FI; path=/; domain=.apple.com
Set-Cookie: ccl=izHQtSPVGso4jrdTGqyAkA==; path=/; domain=.apple.com
```

It would seem like a logical thing to just drop the port from the URL, but unfortunately it's a required field:

[image: port field]

Also the 'Switch to full URL' option doesn't seem to really help, even though the port can be cleared there:

[image: edit full url]

it still appears back after saving:

[image: saved full url]

Is there any way to make this work?

Edit:
My domain is managed through AWS Route 53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATE: maybe it's worth mentioning this is nice as an exercise and show capabilities. However between a Lambda redirection and just a pure Load Balancer redirection, I'd still suggest you go with the ALB-native. It's more performatic (no cold-start, no extra hop), less error-prone (no coding required), for the cost of just aesthetics on a network trace or developer tools. End users would never notice that (you probably browse in lot of these sites everyday and you don't even know). So if you ask me, I'd suggest against going to production with something like this.*

If you want something very simple as a redirect, you could just create a Target Group pointing to a Lambda function that returns a redirect. It doesn't require the overhead of managing a CloudFront distribution or trying to make it work behind a load balancer, as that would require changes in your DNS as well, since you cannot just place CloudFront behind a load balancer (not that I know of, at least).

For your case, I created a Lambda function (Python 3.8) with the following code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = {}
    
    if event.get('headers', {}).get('x-forwarded-proto', '') == 'http':
        print(event)
        response["statusCode"]=302
        response["headers"] = {"Location": f"https://{event['headers']['host']}{event['path']}"}
        response["body"]=""
        
    return response
```

Then I created a new Target Group with that Lambda function as backend:
[image: Create new Target Group as Lambda function]
[image: Select the Lambda created previously]

Finally, I configured my Listener on port 80 to the redirect Target Group:
[image: Configure your Listener on port 80 to the new Target Group]

With this implementation, your 302 redirect will show up as you expected:
[image: location without port]

Comment: Nice use of the lambda:-) My first initial thought would be lambda@edge, but this seems easier.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. Despite what the name suggests, Lambda@Edge is a feature from CloudFront, so you'd need a distribution for that. Lastly, I didn't include "query string" in my redirect above, but you can if you need. You would have to join all the objects in the property `queryStringParameters` from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-alb.html

Comment: I decided too that this wasn't worth the cosmetic gains and it was best to just ditch this and use the native ELB redirects. Thanks for the proof of concept though!

Answer (score 0):

This would still display in your browser's URL field without the port if this is what you're worrying about.

By default interpreters assume that if the protocol is HTTPS then the port is 443 so you do not need to specify anything, when the redirect occurs it does not add a port number to the end unless you specify a non-standard port such as `4430`.

You have to specify the protocol (HTTPS) and port (443) simply because the configuration requires these items, this will not display for the user. This is the same as other AWS configurations such as during the configuration for an ELB.

Comment: Yes, I know it shows correcly in the browser's URL field, but it stil shows the "ugly" format in `curl` output and for example in Chrome dev tools network tab's 'Response headers'  `Location: https://www.example.com:443/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could put CloudFront in front of your server and have that perform https redirect. If you are only using ELB for SSL termination, you could remove it entirely and have CloudFront terminate your SSL. This would save you some money as ELB is pretty expensive if your only using it for one origin server.
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

Comment: My ELB forwards to 4 different target groups, so I cannot remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudFront and set the the origin as the load balancer. Then force HTTPS redirection on the cloud-front with `Viewer Protocol Policy` set to `Redirect HTTP to HTTPS`.

In this approach, all the ELB rules will still be applied.